# Why does __webpack_hash__ never change its value (anymore?)?

Tags: webpack

I'm using `__webpack_hash__` in ejs template files for a while now to prevent browser caching issues since upgrading Webpack to v5. But today I'm seeing the issue that the value it stands for always remains the same and doesn't change after a new build. No matter if I change the contents of the ejs file or the contents of the Javascript entry file and rebuild.
Building works fine as usual, but the variable doesn't change on a new build while IMO it should. I believe this was working fine before, but I'm not 100% sure.

Is there something changed in Webpack? Shouldn't this hash variable change on each new webpack build, at least when some of the files had changed?

Thanks in advance!